# Streaming Dataflow System-Lag issues every few days

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have a streaming dataflow job (SDK 2.7.0). It listens to pub/sub topic,   does some aggregations over time windows, and then outputs both to pub/sub and to Google storage.

Once every few days, the 'System-Lag' / 'Data Watermark' counter in stackdriver would increase rapidly. If I ignore it then the job processing is stopped (nothing will be written to the output topic).
My current solution for this is to the update the job (without stoping it, and using the same code), it replaces the worker instance and the problem is then solved after few minutes. But I doubt if this is the correct approach...

Is this a platform issue? If not, any suggestion on what am I doing wrong?